mv some files in a folder and keep the rest
I am trying to move files using the command below in vain.
mv /gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/$(ls --ignore=mird2.sh --ignore=Results --ignore=slurm* --ignore=scripts --ignore=Gff_data --ignore=Gmm_65_index) /gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/Results/18_31length/GmSG

cannot move '/gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/' to a subdirectory of itself, '/gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/Results/18_31length/GmSG/MiRNA'
I have been using this all the time and it worked perfectly well. I have no idea what am not doing well now.

You can't put the results of $(ls) after the directory name. Only the first result will have the directory prepended, the rest are by themselves. It doesn't distribute the concatenation.

It will only work if ls returns exactly one name. You'll get the error you got if it returns no results at all.

Instead of command substitution, pipe ls to a while read -r filename loop that processes each file found.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Thank you @Barmar for your response. If you don't mind, would you write for me how this should be? I am not good with loops. Thanks again.

Use extended globbing:
shopt -s extglob
mv /gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/!(mird2.sh|Results|slurm*|scripts|Gff_data|Gmm_65_index) /gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/Results/18_31length/GmSG

!(a|b*) expands to everything else than a and b*.

@Otis254: "Thank you" on StackOverflow = upvote/accept :-)

Don't use command substitution, since you only concatenate the first filename to the directory, not all filenames. It also won't work if any names have spaces.
And if ls doesn't return anything, you'll try to move the directory itself. That seems to be what's causing your error.
Pipe the output to a while loop:
ls --ignore=mird2.sh --ignore=Results --ignore=slurm* --ignore=scripts --ignore=Gff_data --ignore=Gmm_65_index | while read -r filename
do
    mv "/gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/$filename" /gpfs/gibbs/project/MiRNA/Results/18_31length/GmSG
done


Not sure why you'd link the "do not parse ls" answer and then proceed to post an answer where you parse ls. This will break on files with newlines in their names, and I don't believe that standard ls implementations support null delimiters so there will always be a blind spot in this type of parsing.

I mainly worry about things like for filename in $(ls...).

Thank you @Barmar this matter is sorted.

What to do when someone answers your question @Otis254
